# NFS lock not working properly

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

I'm getting the following error on an oracle database.

```
ORA-27086: unable to lock file - already in use
```

It tries to lock a file that resides in an NFS mount.

The NFS is on a loopback setup (long story short, I need it this way because of direct nfs) and I traced the error to nlockmgr not going up, even when I restart nfs, nfslock and rpcbind.

Does anybody knows how to get nlockmgr up again?

```
p08[oracle] () /$ cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

Here's the exit for rpcinfo -s:

```
[root@p08 init.d]# rpcinfo -s
   program version(s) netid(s)                         service     owner
    100000  2,3,4     local,udp,tcp,udp6,tcp6          portmapper  superuser
    100011  2,1       tcp,udp                          rquotad     superuser
    100005  3,2,1     tcp6,udp6,tcp,udp                mountd      superuser
    100003  4,3,2     udp6,tcp6,udp,tcp                nfs         superuser
    100227  3,2       udp6,tcp6,udp,tcp                nfs_acl     superuser
    100024  1         tcp6,udp6,tcp,udp                status      29
```

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is server configuration. Try serverfault and/or superuser.

Comment: you are right sir, it was a mistake due to my rush. sorry.